# Visual Studio - Team Foundation

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio with Azure DevOps and Team Foundation.  This works great, and allows myself and others in our team to check-in and check-out files we are working on to keep them in sync, however I want to know if it's possible to set up the workspace in Visual Studio to use a remote location as the local folder.  I know that sounds like an oxymoron, but basically I'd like to keep my Source control folder as it is currently, pointed to the TF Server location, but I want to be able to have my workspace Local Folder defined as a remote location that myself and others outside of my network could have access to.  That way check-in and check-out still works, without having to set up a VPN into my network so the others can use my local folder.

I have seen that there is something available called Remote Workspace, but I'm not very familiar with what it is or how it works.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you want to share your local workspace rather than having remote users simply check out their own workspace? Is it just to save the license fee for  contributors?

Comment: We're all sharing the same code base, and I want to have check-in / check-out working so we don't accidentally overwrite some else's work.

Comment: @Filburt, from what I understand, check-in and check-out in Visual Studio only works when you're sharing the same Local folder for your Workspace, and you have the type set to Server.

Comment: I'd suggest reading up on [Get Started with Azure Repos and Visual Studio - Share your changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/gitquickstart?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio#share-your-changes)

Comment: @Filburt, I understand that is the best practice, but I need to be able to check in check out and I do not want others able to modify the file.  Same way Dreamweaver works.  Only way I know of doing this in VS is using Server workspace with same Local Folder for all users involved.

Comment: You can simply add others as Readers so they can create their own local workspace without being able to commit changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This functionality is very Do-able. I myself implemented this in one of my previous projects.**

Although the Reason was different for the same implementation. I was trying to keep my uncommitted changes safe in case if something happens to my local machine.
We had frequent crashes in our local machines(do not ask why). So, I resolved the issue with the same implementation.

What I did was, I mapped the network location as a drive on my Computer. You can find the details [in this link](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/map-network-drive-windows-10).

Once you are done mapping your network drive, go to TFS Source Control Explorer and set up the workspace using the new network location.

Comment: I truly appreciate your input, however I have already set that up on my local machine.  My question was how to I point the Local folder as a remote location.  It looks like this is the only way and I'll simply need to have users connect via VPN so they can access the shared location.

Comment: Once you are done with mapping the remote location as a drive on your local system. You can simply go and map the workspace in that location. Just like you map it to any other location.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any further help. I am a freelancer and work on similar assignments for DevOps. I am always happy to help the community

Comment: the problem is the mapped drive points to a shared folder on a server within my network.  I need to point the workspace local folder to a shared folder in the cloud so that others OUTSIDE my network can access it

Comment: try this one.
https://www.thewindowsclub.com/map-cloud-storage-drive-windows

Comment: that just might work!  Thank you!